# Geocoder Context in Subclass

Tags: android, geocoding, android-context

My Main Activity is `AddressFinder`, here I start a `AddressController`:

```
AddressController ac = new AddressController();
```

The AddressController should update in some cases:

```
import android.content.Context;
....
private void updateAddresses() throws IOException {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
 for (Address a: address) {
 List<Address> addressIn = geocoder.getFromLocation(a.getLatitude(), 
                                                       a.getLongitude(), 1);
 }
}
```

Now I have no idea which context I have to use. I don't understand how to use it. I tried `this`, `context`, `getBaseContext()`, `getApplicationContext()` but nothing worked. Furthermore i tried to give the Adresscontroller an argument with the `context` (`getApplicationContext`) of the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think i got a solution. In the main activity i use following:

```
ac.updateAddr(getApplicationContext());
```

In the AddressController i changed:

```
public void updateAddr(Context c) throws IOException {
    updateAddresses(c);
}
```

Thats the way I give the context to the `Geocoder` in the `AddressController`. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` class create variable:

```
Context con = this;  
... 
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(con);
```

Maybe use another constructor?:

```
public Geocoder (Context context, Locale locale)
```

Comment: the geocoder is in the Controller, or did u move him too? i tried your suggestion and changed the constructor that i can use the `con` in the controller: `new AddressController(con)` - doesnt work, but thx for the answer.

Comment: in Anroid.developers say
context in constructor isthe Context of the calling Activity

Comment: you sure that you application crash on this constructor?